# Menu scrollbar hiding in css template

Tags: javascript, css, html, templates

my friend downloaded a css template for making a demo website. after a month the template has been started acting as a trojan, the menu bar's scroll stopped working and  some unusual things are happened. Is there any solution to clean this template(its little bit sounds like crazy!!)

thanks